# Why is my UserControl anmation being triggered on all instances of the control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So in the WPF project I'm just starting I have a UserControl that will be eventully functioning as a sort of document tab (I have simplified the code for this question). On the UserControl is a TextBlock, and the desired behavior is that when the user mouses over the control the text should change color. The XAML below works (resources defined in another file) BUT the ColorAnimation happens to every instance of the UserControl, not just the one I'm mousing over. So if I scatter some of these controls over the UI and mouse over one of them, ALL of them change color. Why??? I've tried adding the triggers to the UserControl, the Grid, and the TextBlock itself but it appears to make no difference. As ever, grateful for any advice.

```
<UserControl x:Class="OurCompany.TabControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Height="24" Width="Auto">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="MouseEnterFade">
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TabTitleText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                        Duration="0:0:0.1"
                        To="{DynamicResource FrameBorderColor}"/>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="MouseLeaveFade">
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TabTitleText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                        Duration="0:0:0.1"
                        To="{DynamicResource MenuForegroundColor}"/>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseEnterFade}"/>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseLeaveFade}"/>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
<Grid x:Name="TabGrid" Background="Transparent">        
    <TextBlock x:Name="TabTitleText" Text="{Binding Path=Header}" Margin="10,0,10,0" Foreground="{DynamicResource MenuForegroundBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly in a small test environment. Only the one TextBlock changes the Color I'm mousing over.

Comment: I think I figured out the cause myself. The default Foreground brush is set to a DynamicResource, and the Coloranimation is changing the color property of the resource, which is common to all the instances. If I set the foreground of the TextBlock to "Red" (or any other specific color) it works. Now I just have to figure out how to still get this to work within my themed environment. Thanks for reading anyway.

Comment: You may need to share more of what you have, by chance "TabTitleText" isn't in something using `TextBlock` as a `TargetType` and hitting every control of that type in your tree is it? Like say Template of some sort...?

Comment: <Storyboard x:Key="MouseEnterFade" x:Shared="false"> will let you get a new instance of storyboard when needed. That is how you will solve your issue.